# modelformset __iter__ overloading problem

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm writing the custom modelformset. I need that forms to be sorted by value of field "ordering". I overloaded `__iter__` method of BaseFormSet in my child formset class.

#### My class inherited from BaseFormSet:

```
class SortedCatForms(BaseFormSet):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.forms.sort(
                            key=lambda form: form['ordering'].value())) #line 38, the problem line.

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return list(self)[index]
```

#### I use it in my modelformset:

```
OrderCatsFormSet = modelformset_factory(ParentCategory,
                                    fields=('category', 'ordering'),
                                    formset=SortedCatForms,
                                    extra=0)
```

#### *The problem is:*

> Caught TypeError while rendering: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>
> Exception Location: ...forms.py in `__iter__`, line 38

But in source BaseFormSet:

```
def __iter__(self):
    """Yields the forms in the order they should be rendered"""
    return iter(self.forms)
```

**What is wrong in my code? How to do it in right way?**

Edit:

[full traceback](http://dpaste.com/613630/)

Edit:

After @bobince's advice my code became this:

```
class SortedCatForms(BaseFormSet):
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(
            sorted(self.forms, key=lambda form: form['ordering'].value()))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    return list(self)[index]
```

It's returns empty list without forms. Are problem in `__getitem__`?

Comment: Might need to see more of the traceback.

Comment: I added full traceback in edit of my question.

Comment: One gotcha is done, that is valuably. But I still have a problem with this issue and work around it without avail. My formset returns empty list. I would be grateful for your attention to this issue!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not familiar enough with Django to judge whether this is the *right* way, but here's a simple gotcha:

```
return iter(self.forms.sort( ...
```

`sort()` is a method on a list that sorts it in-place and returns `None`. You probably meant:

```
return iter(sorted(self.forms, ...
```

Comment: looks right, thanks for it. Now it's no exception in there, but and no forms rendered. In docs tells: Formsets can also be indexed into, which returns the corresponding form. If you override `__iter__`, you will need to also override `__getitem__` to have matching behavior. Could this be the reason for the continuation of my problem? If it is, how to do this?