# Changing the display order of forms in a formset

Tags: python, django

I am displaying a modelformset and I would like the forms to be ordered by the contents of one of its fields. So I want to use the equivalent of `SomeModel.objects.filter(whatever).order_by('somefield')` for a (model)formset in a template.

How can I do this?

Note that `can_order` does not do what I want (it must be automatic, not user specified). I have also tried other things, like the dictsort filter, but that produces unpredictable output (i.e. not ordered by the specified field).

I even tried `{% regroup formset by somefield as sorted_formset %}`, but the resulting `sorted_formset` cannot be used (iterated) as a normal formset.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset displays almost exactly what you need. Just put your ordered query as the parameter for `queryset`

Comment: got my name in the Django project with [this patch](https://github.com/django/django/commit/680268a683) :-).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To complete the answers. There are two ways how you can control the order of forms in the formset: formsets respect order of given queryset (this is shown in other replies). Another way (if you want to have the order of the forms fully under control) is to define custom formset class and override `__iter__` and `__getitem__` methods:

```
from django.forms import BaseModelFormSet

class MyModelBaseFormset(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __iter__(self):
        """Yields the forms in the order they should be rendered"""
        return ...

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Returns the form at the given index, based on the rendering order"""
        return ...


MyModelFormset = modelformset_factory(model=MyModel, formset=MyModelBaseFormset, queryset=...)
```

This approach is described in the Django documentation:

> Iterating over the formset will render the forms in the order they
>   were created. You can change this order by providing an alternate
>   implementation for the `__iter__()` method.
>
> Formsets can also be indexed into, which returns the corresponding
>   form. If you override `__iter__`, you will need to also override
>   `__getitem__` to have matching behavior.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.BaseFormSet

The example of implementing these methods is for example in this SO thread: [modelformset __iter__ overloading problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393615/modelformset-iter-overloading-problem).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was struggling with a pre-filled formset that could be modified after the related objects have been generated automatically. But since I ordered them when passing the queryset and also restricting the foreign-key field to another list (same ordering as the queryset) it messed up. When I created the objects in the expected order it worked and i now finally know why. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

if you didn't defined Formset, this is  the "inline code" version:

```
FS=inlineformset_factory(ParentClass,ChildClass)
formset=FS(instance=parentobject,
           queryset=parentobject.childobject_set.order_by("-time_begin")
          )
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @john-peters answer above, for pointing me in the right direction.  But here is a better way:

```
MyFormset(inlineformset_factory(...)):

  def get_queryset(self):
    return super(MyFormset, self).get_queryset().order_by('myfieldname')
```

This way you do not have to copy or mess with django's code and potentially cause breakage down the road.. just take the queryset that django gives you and override the ordering.  I have used this in my own code, it works.

EDIT.  After working on this a bit I realize that although it appears to work fine, it somehow messes up the logic in BaseInlineFormset.get_queryset(), resulting in duplicate database queries.  However, in the hopes that someone will comment on this and correct it, I will leave it here.  Meanwhile, I have another solution which DOES WORK and does not result in redundant queries.. as follows:

```
MyFormset(inlineformset_factory(...)):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = self.queryset.order_by('myfieldname')
```

This modifies the queryset at a safe time, before anything is done with it.  In my code I am also doing .select_related() here, which greatly speeds up my large modelformsets!

Comment: You may getting "duplicates" if your queryset is dealing with an M2M relation.  In that case, just pop a `.distinct()` at the end of the queryset.

Comment: Any chance you can give an example of this in a `form.py` file (i.e. like where does `inlineformset_factory` come from ?)

Comment: This doesn't work if your aim is to have the extra blank forms interspersed in amongst the queryset results.

Comment: @AdamBarnes Unless something changed in newer versions of Django that I don't know about, the `extra` rows always have to be at the end of the ModelFormset, numerically.  You can reorder the elements in javascript or sort them in your view before outputting them so that they appear on the page in a different order.  But the formset always generates the extra's last.

Comment: @little_birdie I do believe you're right - I ended up doing `{'forms': sorted(formset.forms, key=lambda form: form.initial['position'])}` and `{% for form in forms %}` (instead of `{% for form in formset %}`).  I haven't noticed any issues.

Comment: That works.. but I think it is no better (worse in some ways) than just setting `order_by` on the queryset.  In some of my formsets I have column like your `position` column that I order_by.. and then I use jQuery sortable so that the user can move the rows around.  (There's a little javascript to keep the row at the correct width while they are dragging it so it looks nice).. and then when they are done dragging I run javascript that renumbers  that column in the order they are displayed.. so if they save the formset it will save the order they dragged it into.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to rantanplan's comment I found a solution. I could not use the method as described in the link above because I don't know what the queryset is going to be (this is a complex form with nested formsets).

Anyway, I found a solution by overriding the get_queryset method from Django's BaseInlineFormSet Class. 
I copied it below, including my mod, in case googlers find it helpful.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    '''
    Copied this method from Django code and modified the ordering statement
    '''
    if not hasattr(self, '_queryset'):
        if self.queryset is not None:
            qs = self.queryset
        else:
            qs = self.model._default_manager.get_query_set()

        # If the queryset isn't already ordered we need to add an
        # artificial ordering here to make sure that all formsets
        # constructed from this queryset have the same form order.
        if not qs.ordered:
# MY MOD IS HERE:
#            qs = qs.order_by(self.model._meta.pk.name)
            qs = qs.order_by('order_index')
#/MOD

        # Removed queryset limiting here. As per discussion re: #13023
        # on django-dev, max_num should not prevent existing
        # related objects/inlines from being displayed.
        self._queryset = qs
    return self._queryset
```

Comment: @little_birdie's answer below is better.  Just use Python inheritance to modify the queryset that is returned from the super method.

Answer (score 2):

A more simpler way but it might not apply in every situation but if you can afford it just define ordering in models Meta class:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
     ...
     class Meta:
          ordering = ("name", )
```

Formset will respect the queryset's ordering which will respect the Meta class variable's value.